# Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code was working great this morning but now gives "Must declare the scalar variable "@Quantity" I have tried many of the suggestions on this and other sites - but still will not resolve the problem. The only change I made to the form from this morning was that I added a checkbox. I tried removing the @Quantity var and the error just goes to @operator (next in line)  My code that is giving the error is below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection TSTTWI = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TS-ERP01;Initial Catalog=TST-TWI;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            SqlCommand nc = new SqlCommand ("Insert into NCM (Quantity, Operator, NonConformance, Date, Description, PN, RMA) Values (@Quantity, @Operator, @NonConformance, @Date, @Description, @PN, @RMA)", TSTTWI);


            TSTTWI.Open();
            nc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            TSTTWI.Close();


            nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtQuantity.Text);
            nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operator", txtName.Text);
            nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NonConformance", txtNonConf.Text);
            nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtDate.Text);
            nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescript.Text);
            nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PN", DDPartNo.Text);
            nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RMA", txtRMA.Text);





            if (IsPostBack)
            {
```

Comment: Are all of your database columns text, including Quantity and Date?

Comment: Did you notice that you have ExecuteNonQuery before adding parameters to your command? Where is supposed to find the parameters the command when you execute it?

Comment: @Steve - but this code was working great in the morning ;)

Comment: @Steve, Thanks - boy was that dumb. Anyway, it is throwing a different error now but that is beyond the scope of this discussion.

Comment: Then please delete the question yourself.

Comment: Also look at that _Date_ column. It is a reserved keyword, needs square brackets around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would seem you're trying to execute nc before you add the parameters.  Maybe try moving this block below the part where you're adding parameters.

```
nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtQuantity.Text);
nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operator", txtName.Text);
nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NonConformance", txtNonConf.Text);
nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtDate.Text);
nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescript.Text);
nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PN", DDPartNo.Text);
nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RMA", txtRMA.Text);

TSTTWI.Open();
nc.ExecuteNonQuery();
TSTTWI.Close();
```

Comment: Yes, maybe.....

Comment: Thank you@Steve - yeah pretty dumb on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing penalty of things wrong at the same time.

```
TSTTWI.Open();
nc.ExecuteNonQuery();
TSTTWI.Close();
```

With this code, you are opening the connection, executing the command and closing the connection. Then below this line you start to add the parameters

```
nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtQuantity.Text);
nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operator", txtName.Text);
....
```

The correct way is:

```
try{
    TSTTWI.Open();

    nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtQuantity.Text);
    nc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operator", txtName.Text);
    ....

    nc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    TSTTWI.Close();
}
catch(Exception exception){

 //log the exception somewhere 
}
```

Comment: @geekzster Originally when I pasted from my code, I had log4net logging the exception to database so I thought it doesn't make any sense to post that code as well so I kept it blank just for viewing. I have updated it with a comment